# Measurability of the set of non-tangential boundary points

Tags: cv.complex-variables, measure-theory

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb D:=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|<1\}$. Suppose that $\overline S$,  the Euclidean closure of $S$
  meets $\mathbb T=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\}$. A point $\xi=e^{i\theta}\in \overline S\cap \mathbb T$ is called a  non-tangential boundary
  point, if there is a cone 
  $$S_\alpha(\theta):=\{z\in \mathbb D: |\arg(1-e^{-i\theta}z)|<\alpha,  \;{\rm Re}\,(e^{-i\theta}z)\geq 0\},$$
  and a sequence $(z_n)$ in $S\cap S_\alpha$ such that $\lim z_n=\xi$. My question is,
 whether the set $S_{nt}$ of all non-tangential boundary points of $S$ is Lebesgue measurable 
  in $\mathbb T$. I would be surprised if this were the case, but could not come up with a counter example. This is connected to the Brown-Shields-Zeller theorem.

Comment: Can you proofread the definition of the cone? How are $\xi$ and $\theta$ related ?  The real part is of the right quantity?

Comment: I have now  given the definition of $\xi=e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For given $\alpha$ the corresponding set of nontangential boundary points is a $G_{\delta}$ set, since the cone must contain points of $S$ in annuli arbitrarily close to the unit circle. Here $G_n$  consists of boundary points $\xi$ where the cone $S_\alpha(\theta)$ intersects $\{z: 1-1/n<|z|<1\} \cap S$. Thus
 the set of all non tangential boundary points is a $G_{\delta \sigma }$ set and in particular a Borel set.

Comment: Could you please give us for fixed $\alpha$ the sets $G_n$ in the $G_\delta$ representation?

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't see why this set $G_n$ you define should be open in $\mathbb T$?

Comment: Since the cone intersected with annulus is open in the disk, if it contains a point z  of S and you shift it slightly the shifted cone will still contain z.

Comment: Okay; very nice